# two webPage on single UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, uiwebview

i am making an iPad application,

i want to load 2 webPage on single UIWebView one after another,

1st webpage should come when i load my application,and 2nd webpage should come on click of cell of tableView,

so,inside my didLoad method i am writing this (1st webpage),

```
NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

it works fine..

but on the same page on same webview on click of cell of tableView i want to load another page,(2nd webpage)

i written code for the same, when i click on cell of tableView graph is not displaying,

do i need to clear webpage or reload webpage something like that ?

**Help Me Guys, Thanx in Advance !!**

Comment: What is the code that you have written for loading of second web view?

Comment: Are you sure that the code for loading the second web view is running? You might want to verify via logging. Code responding to events not running is a very common mistake.

Comment: NSString *urlAddress1 = @” http://www.yahoo.com”; //Create a URL object. NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress1]; //URL Requst Object NSURLRequest *requestObj1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1]; //Load the request in the UIWebView. [webView loadRequest:requestObj1];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call this method,

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  NSString *urlAddress = @”http://www.google.com”;

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see from your comment that you use a wrong URL format for the second request:

```
NSString *urlAddress1 = @”yahoo.com”; //Create a URL object.
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress1]; //URL Requst Object 
NSURLRequest *requestObj1 = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url1]; //Load the request in the 
UIWebView. [webView loadRequest:requestObj1];
```

The URL has to begin with

```
http://
```

Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: http:// is also there in my URL, i forgot to write here, is there any other mistake ?